# RowVersion and Linq to Sql

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm using [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to enable optimistic concurrency for my database. I used code-first to get the rowVersion column added to the database and everything looks good. However, I am not sure how the rowVersion column is used in linq to sql queries in my data access layer. Is it automatically handled by ef/linq to sql or is it something that I have to explicitly specify? 
In the article, the rowVersion property is added to OriginalValues collection for that entity by `db.Entry(departmentToUpdate).OriginalValues["RowVersion"] = rowVersion;`. How can I do this with linq to sql?